# Moving cell data into different worksheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I'm sure this is a fairly simple error that I'm making but I'm struggling to work out what order to put things in.

I have a set of data that is in one worksheet and I want to move certain cells of data over to other worksheets ('costs 1' through to 'costs 5').

I've used formula in excel (unique, and countifs) to work out how many rows of data should be moved into each worksheet and this is in column S (ProdNum).

I also have a total number of Accounts in Cell V3. Ideally the code should only loop this many times (i.e. total accounts = total number of worksheets to copied across into) - 5 is the max but it could be as low as 1. I can only Google/think of looping the array from LBound to UBound so it's looping all the way through at the moment...however that isn't a big deal at the moment.

The biggest deal is that the all data is going into all the worksheets - it is not stopping at the number of rows I want it to stop at before moving onto the next worksheet.

Here is an example of the data

| Row number | Column J... | Column S... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 5 | Product name 1 | 1 |
| 6 | Product name 2 | 3 |
| 7 | Product name 3 | 1 |
| 8 | Product name 4 | 1 |
| 9 | Product name 5 | 1 |
| 10 | Product name 6 | 1 |
| 11 | Product name 7 | 1 |

In this example, Product Name 1 through to 7 will appear in all 5 "costs" worksheets.

Whereas what i want to happen is:

- Product name 1 should appear in (the Worksheet:) costs 1,
- Product name 2 - 4 should appear in costs 2
- Product name 5 should appear in costs 3
- Product name 6 should appear in costs 4
- Product name 7 should appear in costs 5

Can anyone help me? Also if you think the code is working over-time by looping through the 5 worksheets then I would really appreciate some help there as well.

thank you.

edit:

I've edited the code slightly to remove a msgbox that was interfering with the question and I had used the incorrect variable half way through (changed from status_1 to TotalAcc.

To add further to this and what I am expecting it to do:

```
Option Explicit
Sub startdata()
    
    Dim i                   As Long
    Dim a                   As Long
    Dim ProdNum             As Long
    
    Dim prod                As Long
    Dim prod1               As Long
    
    Dim Transaction         As Double
    Dim Incidental          As Double
    Dim Weighting           As Double
    
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet
    Dim ProdName            As String
    Dim TotalAcc            As String
    Dim InxW                As Long
    Dim WshtNames           As Variant
    
    
    WshtNames = Array("Costs 1", "Costs 2", "Costs 3", "Costs 4", "Costs 5")
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    With ws
        
        TotalAcc = .Cells(3, 22).Value
    
            ProdNum = 5
'The next bit of code I would hope is going to start off the loop of setting the number of times it needs to loop (starting at 5, to TotalAcc (which is a number no higher than 5) + 5. So in other words from '5 to 10 '.
            For ProdNum = 5 To TotalAcc+ 5
'I'm now telling it to loop through each of the worksheets as set above in my worksheet array.
                For InxW = LBound(WshtNames) To UBound(WshtNames)
'So it knows which cell to copy across I have set "prod" to the value of the loop of ProdNum - i.e. starting at 5,19 (in the example table above this would have a value of 1). On the next loop though, I am expecting the row '5' (i.e. ProdNum) to turn to a 6. This would give me a value of 3 - as per the table above.
               
                prod = .Cells(ProdNum, 19).Value
'The data actually lives on cells starting at row 3. So, to start the loop of the potentially multiple sets of data to be copied, I have told it to start at 3 and finish at prod (currently "1") + 2. So my example above, the data would first start at 3 and finish at 3.
'On the next loop I now have a Prod = 3 therefore I would expect i (which is now 4) to loop from 4 through to 6..... hold up! I think I'm going wrong here...."i" will grow from 3 to 4, but "prod" might not be high enough, i need to add a cumulative prodnumber to the loop not just the absolute amount for that account...          
                For i = 3 To prod + 2
                    
                    ProdName= .Cells(i, 10).Value
                    Transaction = .Cells(i, 14).Value
                    Weighting = .Cells(i, 12).Value
                    
                    With Worksheets(WshtNames(InxW))
                        .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = ProdName
                        .Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = Transaction
                        .Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = Weighting
                    End With
                    
                Next i
                
            Next InxW
            
        Next ProdNum
    End With
    

End Sub
```

EDITED:

I've changed it so that it is now looking at the cumulative next set of cells (starting at ProdNum, 20), I've also cracked the bit about the same data being pushed into each costs tab. (but adding a ProdNum + 1 AND a new variable of inum - and also adding 1 to it after each loop).

I'm nearly there...however as I have "i" as my variable for getting the data and where I'm putting the data - the cell reference starts at the incorrect point in the "costs" tabs now. In other words, my costs tab 1 starts at row 3. When it gets one bit of data as per the table above, it moves onto the next loop (great!) - the next loop starts at row 4 in the data tab - but writes it to row 4 as well in the costs 2 tab. Is it possible to run 2 loops at the same time (if I rename one side of this code for example):

```
                sh.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 10).Value        'ProdName
                sh.Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value        'Transaction
                sh.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 12).Value        'Weighting
```

Here is the new code so far:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub startdata()
    Dim i           As Long, ProdNum As Long, prod As Long, TotalAcc As Long, inum As Long
    Dim ws          As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, mtch, WshtNames As Variant
    
WshtNames = Array("Costs 1", "Costs 2", "Costs 3", "Costs 4", "Costs 5")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    TotalAcc = ws.Cells(3, 22).Value
    If TotalAcc = 0 Then MsgBox "Nothing has been imported, please try importing again.", vbCritical: Exit Sub
    ProdNum = 5
    inum = 5
    
    
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        mtch = Application.Match(sh.Name, WshtNames, 0)
        If sh.Name <> ws.Name And Not IsError(mtch) Then
            prod = ws.Cells(ProdNum, 20).Value
            'in cells(inum, 21) and the rows below are the starting points for where I want "i" to look at. In other words, it always starts at 3 (for row 3), and then the row below gets added by the number of rows for the next set. In this case the first set is 1, and the second set is 3 - therefore inum starts off at 3, on the second loop = 4, and the third loop = 7.           
            i = ws.Cells(inum, 21).Value
            For i = i To prod + 2
                sh.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 10).Value        'ProdName
                sh.Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value        'Transaction
                sh.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 12).Value        'Weighting
            Next i
            ProdNum = ProdNum + 1
            inum = inum + 1
            
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Final edit - I was being a little slow at the end there with the where to ensure the right cell was being written to for the destination part of the code.

But here it is:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub startdata()
    Dim i           As Long, b As Long, ProdNum As Long, prod As Long, TotalAcc As Long, inum As Long
    Dim ws          As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, mtch, WshtNames As Variant
    
WshtNames = Array("Costs 1", "Costs 2", "Costs 3", "Costs 4", "Costs 5")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    TotalAcc = ws.Cells(3, 22).Value
    If TotalAcc = 0 Then MsgBox "Nothing has been imported, please try importing again.", vbCritical: Exit Sub
    ProdNum = 5
    inum = 5
    
    'For ProdNum = 5 To TotalAcc + 5 'this loop does not influence what is coming. It looks useless...
    
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        mtch = Application.Match(sh.Name, WshtNames, 0)
        If sh.Name <> ws.Name And Not IsError(mtch) Then
            prod = ws.Cells(ProdNum, 20).Value
'in cells(inum, 21) and the rows below are the starting points for where I want "i" to look at. In other words, it always starts at 3 (for row 3), and then the row below gets added by the number of rows for the next set. In this case the first set is 1, and the second set is 3 - therefore inum starts off at 3, on the second loop = 4, and the third loop = 7.    
            i = ws.Cells(inum, 21).Value
            b = 3

            For i = i To prod + 2
      
            
                sh.Cells(b + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 10).Value        'ProdName
                sh.Cells(b + 1, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value        'Transaction
                sh.Cells(b + 1, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 12).Value        'Weighting

                b = b + 1
            Next i

            
            ProdNum = ProdNum + 1
            inum = inum + 1
            
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure you use `Option Explicit` some of your variables are not declared like `status_1`. And please [edit] your question to add how is determined which product goes where? It is pretty unclear which result you want and how to get there.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ okay thank you - I've commented the code to make it a little clearer, and removed some excess bits that were confusing it. status_1 was left in by mistake and should have been TotalAcc. As I was commenting I think I've found a mistake, am I going along the right path?

Comment: Please explain (in words) what do you wan doing in the loop starting with `For ProdNum = 5 To status_1 + 5`.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have edited the code since you wrote this I think. The status_1 has been replaced by TotalAcc. Let me know if it's still not clear and I will try again!

Comment: Since `ProdNum` is never used inside its loop, which to be its meaning. If `TotalAcc` will be bigger than zero, the loop ` For i = 3 To prod + 2` will do the same thing but more times. I suppose that you have a different expectation form it and I would like to hear which is it...

Comment: I expected ProdNum to be increased by 1 on its' loop. This would have changed the reference cell the determines what "prod" is - i.e. Prod = .cells(ProdNum, 19).Value --> that would start at 5 and finish at TotalAcc+5 ---> Prod would therefore = cells5,19 on the first loop, cells 6,19 on the second loop and so on. The reason i would want Prod to increase in value is so the loop varies in size (i through to prod +2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It is more compact and it should do what (I understood) you need. No need to so many variable, which only are meant to confuse somebody trying to understand the code. It contains a useless loop (commented), I asked for clarification in an above comment, but I kept it...

```
Sub startdata()
    Dim i  As Long, ProdNum As Long, prod As Long, status_1 As Long, TotalAcc As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, mtch, WshtNames As Variant, inum As Long
       
    WshtNames = Array("Costs 1", "Costs 2", "Costs 3", "Costs 4", "Costs 5")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    TotalAcc = ws.cells(3, 22).value
    If TotalAcc = 0 Then MsgBox "Nothing has been imported, please try importing again.", vbCritical: Exit Sub
    ProdNum = 5: inum = 5
    
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        mtch = Application.match(sh.Name, WshtNames, 0)
            If sh.Name <> ws.Name And Not IsError(mtch) Then                 
                 For ProdNum = 5 To TotalAcc + 5 'this loop does not influence what is coming. It looks useless...
                    prod = ws.cells(ProdNum, 19).value
                    i = ws.Cells(inum, 21).Value
                    For i = 3 To prod + 2
                         sh.cells(i + 1, 2).value = ws.cells(i, 10).value   'ProdName
                         sh.cells(i + 1, 6).value = ws.cells(i, 14).value   'Transaction
                         sh.cells(i + 1, 5).value = ws.cells(i, 12).value  'Weighting
                    Next i
                 Next ProdNum
            End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The above code iterates between all existing sheets and chooses only the one from the array...

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru however, within the Costs sheets the starting position is always row 4 (which is initially achieved by i+1. In other words, when you go to a different costs sheet, you still start a row 4. However, as we iterate through the loop I would like it to start at row 3 in the data sheet and then move down the rows. So in the example table above, you would never go back to "Product Name 1" one it has been moved into the costs 1 sheet.

Comment: @Boswell I asked in a comment and I made a comment above, too... What do you expect from the loop starting with `For ProdNum = 5 To TotalAcc + 5`? Now, does the above code do what you need? If not, what does it return against you want to?

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter too soon on my reply - i will answer your comment in 2 moments.

Comment: i've replied to you above.

Comment: I've just realised what you meant about "Now, do you really want using i variable for both 'source-destination' sheets? Shouldn't be used that ProdNum to define the range in one of them? I cannot imagine how the data you deal with looks..." - yes you're entirely right, and I need to change this.

Comment: @Boswell OK. Adapted the above code to increment the `prod` according to `ProdNum` value. Please, try the updated version and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank you, however, it's still copying all the data into each costs sheet. I've stepped through it and it is moving onto the next product set **before** it moves onto the next costs sheet. I.e. once it has finished one itteration of "For i = 3 To prod + 2
sh.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 10).Value   'ProdName
                         sh.Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value   'Transaction
                         sh.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 12).Value  'Weighting
                    Next i
It should then move onto the next costs sheet (but it's not).

Comment: I am afraid that without seeing your workbook and without understanding of what you try accomplishing, I cannot help. I only tried to make your code more compact and make it iterating between the sheets name in the array. What you try doing is still not clear for me...

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru - I didn't want to write an explanation again because i guess the way i've done it is quite confusing and I didn't want to mess you around. However, I've now edited the code and it nearly works - however I need to change the variable being used on the destination sheet. I always want it to start at row 3.

Comment: I've added a comment to the code to explain how it knows where to start "i" from (but that is only useful for the source, not the destination!)

Comment: @Boswell Nobody could understand about `i = ws.Cells(inum, 21).Value`, looking to your initial question... I will add it in the above code, just to feel it is more complete.